# Как объединить наследуемый класс из других файлов?

Tags: javascript, классы

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно организовать расширяемый класс с помощью наследования из других файлов?

Или возможно как то по другому организовать данный код?

Суть в том чтобы расширять класс из других файлов если они подключены, пытаюсь добиться что то типа модульности

```js
///////////// Код из файла 1 (Главный файл)
class MainClass {
  constructor() {
    console.log('Главный класс');
  }
}
let main = new MainClass();
// Как из этого файла получить доступ к методам из других файлов
main.newMethod1();
main.newMethod2();

///////////// Код из файла 2
class Items extends MainClass {
  newMethod1() {
    console.log('Запуск из файла 2');
  }
}

///////////// Код из файла 3
class Values extends MainClass {
  newMethod2() {
    console.log('Запуск из файла 3');
  }
}
```

Comment: Это код работать не должен и не будет. Даже если поместить всё в один файл. И расширяемых классов не существует.

Comment: @Qwertiy, я знаю, хочу создать модульность из классов, возножно как то по другому переписать нужно. Есть идеи как такое реализовать? а тов js я новичок, всего несколько дней изучаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В JavaScript можно наследоваться только от одного класса/объекта. Объект имеет единственный [[Prototype]]. И класс может расширить только один другой класс. Но если очень хочется, то есть "примеси" (mixins).

Вот пример использования:

```js
function extend(target, source) {
  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(source.prototype)
    .filter((key) => !~['constructor', 'prototype'].indexOf(key))
    .forEach((key) => {
      Object.defineProperty(target, key, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(source.prototype, key));
    });
}

class MainClass {
  constructor() {
    console.log('Главный класс');
  }
}

class Items {
  newMethod1() {
    console.log('Запуск из файла 2');
  }
}

class Values {
  newMethod2() {
    console.log('Запуск из файла 3');
  }
}

let main = new MainClass();
extend(main, Items);
extend(main, Values);

main.newMethod1();
main.newMethod2();
```